# Stream All Audio to Speakers

Tags: audio, streaming

I'm looking for a device that will wirelessly stream my computer (13" Macbook Pro) audio to my 5.1 speakers. I've seen that AirPort supports 2.0 streaming of iTunes music, but I'd like support for all audio and surround sound (for games and movies). Does anyone know of a product or software for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered Airfoil by Rogue Amoeba? http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to say, this does exactly what you want it to do. There is an option in the app to capture all system audio, although it can have an ever so slight amount of lag. Might be an issue for gaming.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [WiFi2HiFi](http://www.wifi2hifi.com) app. It can stream audio from any computer program to the iPhone, iPod or iPad:

> Use WiFi2HiFi to turn your iPhone into a wireless audio receiver for your stereo system or sound-dock. Combined with the desktop app WiFi2HiFi Station you can listen to whatever audio program is playing on your computer.
>
> Plug your iPod or iPhone into your hi-fi and enjoy your favorite music program, web radio or streaming service in crystal clear stereo quality.
>
> WiFi2HiFi Station acts like an additional audio output on your computer. This allows the application to provide streaming support for all popular audio programs on the Mac and PC.